# how to put controller and action in image_button_tag in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

`<%= button_to '+',{:controller=>"line_items",:action=>'create',:menu_id=> line_item.menu_item,:remote=>true}%>`

I want to put the controller and action into the following `image_submit_tag`:

`<%= image_submit_tag('../images/plus.ico') %>`

I am new in rails.Please tell me the correct syntax for `image_submit_tag`.

Comment: I dont think this tag takes those arguments. you can check the following [documention](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things I need to answer before i get to your question.

First use rails RESTful route helpers rather than spelling out the controller/action.  Hence in your case the route would be:

```
line_items_path(menu_id: line_item.menu_item), remote: true, method: :post
```

I prefer using link_to rather than button_to.  It's just more standard.

```
<%= link_to line_items_path(menu_id: line_item.menu_item), remote: true, method: :post do %>
   <%=image_tag("path/to/image", height:'32',width:'32')%>
<% end %>
```

That said I saw the path to your image was: '../images/plus.ico'

using the asset pipeline you should never need to have "../" before your image path.  Are you putting your assets in app/assets/images directory?  If not you should.

Comment: I am getting the gollowing error: "undefined method menu_item_id"

Comment: I just guessed you had menu_item_id...  just use menu_item although that probably means you have non-standard rails naming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Button_to in following manner to show an image inside of it. If you want to complete remove the look of a button around the image you can do that through CSS.

> ```
> <%= button_to {:controller=>"line_items",:action=>'create',:menu_id=>line_item.menu_item,:remote=>true} do%>                
>     <%=image_tag("path/to/image", height:'32',width:'32')%>
> <%end%>
> ```

Comment: I want to completely remove the button around the image.Do u have that css?

Comment: CSS
style="border: 0px; background: none; outline: none"